# Ruby - Print specific value from hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can print the amount from the following hash? The hash is stored inside a output variable.

And I want to print only the amount "12.37".

output = `{:next_page_token=>nil, :group_definitions=>nil, :results_by_time=>[{:time_period=>{:start=>"2022-07-01", :end=>"2022-08-01"}, :total=>{"BlendedCost"=>{:amount=>"12.3766372967", :unit=>"USD"}}, :groups=>[], :estimated=>false}], :dimension_value_attributes=>[]}`

Comment: `output[:results_by_time].pick(:total).values.pick(:amount).to_f.floor(2)` => `12.37`

Comment: main.rb:8:in `<main>': undefined method `pick' for #<Array:0x0055bf8d36f338> (NoMethodError)

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#pick

Comment: is there any alternate way? just curious

Comment: `p output[:results_by_time][0][:total]["BlendedCost"][:amount].to_f.floor(2)`

Comment: Why are you using a version of Ruby on Rails that has been unmaintained for several years and has unpatched security vulnerabilities? That is a very bad idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html) and follow the path to the value:

```
output.dig(:results_by_time, 0, :total, 'BlendedCost', :amount)
#=> "12.3766372967"

amount = output.dig(:results_by_time, 0, :total, 'BlendedCost', :amount)
Float(amount).round(2)
#=> 12.38
```